# Add element to array collections.update in meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

```
    Polls.update({_id: id}, {$set : {already_voted[length]: ip});
```

Now this obviously doesn't work. I can't simply put a variable "length" in there.

Basically I have `already_voted` which is an array and I want to add a new ip to this array. The way I handle this currently is by getting the old length and using the old length as the new index to add the element.

I am wondering how I should go about doing this as my current setup does not work.

**To clarify** : I don't have the whole array, I just want to add a new element into the array in the Poll document.

Comment: Do you mean you "have" the whole array and you want to add the member that is not present in the stored document array? It's not really clear what you are saying.

Comment: I don't have the whole array. I just have a value that I want to add into an array called `already_voted` in my `Polls` documents.

Comment: That makes it clearer and now you have an answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the `$push` Mongo operator:

`Polls.update({ _id: id },{ $push: { already_voted: ip }})`

See the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

Comment: Better yet. Combine that with $set in case it's a new document, adding `upsert`

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy to add element to array in collection in meteor:

```
collection.update({_id: "unique id"},{$push:{already_voted: ip}});
```

You can even user upsert instead of update as per you requirement.
something like this:

```
collection.upsert({_id: "unique id"},{$push:{already_voted: ip}});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer appears to be very similar to the existing and accepted answer, plus its comments. A new answer to an old question should add new information if it is to be useful. Please read the [answer] pages to see how to write a good answer.